# How to count occurrence of a value per column on every table in postgres schema

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to get some auditing data from my postgres (10) database.  I want to use one value, and match every column on every table in a schema to find the number and percentage of matches.  The result set would look something like:

| table_name | column_name | count_matched | count_unmatched | percentage_matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| person | first_name | 10 | 100 | 10% |
| person | last_name | 5 | 100 | 5% |

Can this be done?  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, you can use information_schema.columns and information_schema.tables, to retrieve all necessary information. With stored procedures and dynamic SQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ecpg-dynamic.html I think you can achieve your goal. But execution will probably be slow and the stored procedure complicated to write.

Comment: does it have to be in SQL? following Zeppi's comment, can you take a snapshot of information_schema and do a post-processing in another language?

Comment: I can't be bothered to write a solution but you can certainly do this in pure postgres, using plpgsql and a lot of dynamic sql.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to loop over database tables if you write code and then
you should loop over distinct values of each column and count each distinct value in that column

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) AS some_alias FROM table_name;`

then you should use some aggregate functions to add and subtract and compare with the total count of a column to find such a result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tested solution in Python (I understand it's not exactly the approach you were looking for, but automation is loads easier with this).

A pic of the result:
[csv file with the table as per format specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4u44.jpg)

```
# You need these 4 packages. 
# Please install using pip - the package manager of Python. Ref: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#use-pip-for-installing
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import io

# Provide your credentials
database = 'something'
user = 'something'
password = 'something'
host = 'something'

# Create the connection
connection_string = '''postgresql+psycopg2://'''+user+''':'''+password+'''@'''+host+'''/'''+database
postgres_engine = sa.create_engine(connection_string)
conn = psycopg2.connect(database=database, user=user, password=password, host=host)
conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
conn.commit()

# Create cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.rollback() # reqd as safety  

# Specify schema
my_schema = 'required_schema'
# Specify required table names
reqd_tables = ['require_table1'] # E.g: If I have 2 tables: ['table1', 'table2']

# Optional step: if columns in metadata table that displays schema names and table names are not known.
# For example, I was not sure how my metadata table looked at all. So, first I executed the below to view the 1st 2 rows of metadata.
# For me, column with schema names is 'table_schema' & column with table names is 'table_name'
pd.read_sql_query(f"""SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns;""", con=conn).head(2)

# Reqd value
reqd_value = 500

# A Pandas dataframe to collate the computation for each column
collator = pd.DataFrame(columns=['table_name', 'column_name', 'count_matched', 'count_unmatched', 'percentage_matched'])

for table in reqd_tables:
    # Get all columns in table
    all_cols = pd.read_sql_query(f"""SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = '{my_schema}' AND table_name = '{table}';""", con=conn).values.tolist()
    all_cols = [x[0] for x in all_cols] # just a Python thing to flatten list of list (as returned by Postgres to a flat list. Eg: [[c1], [c2]] to [c1, c2]
    for col in all_cols:
        count_matched = list(pd.read_sql_query(f"""SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN {col} = {reqd_value} THEN 1 END) AS count FROM {my_schema}.{table};""", con=conn)['count'])[0]
        total = list(pd.read_sql_query(f"""SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {my_schema}.{table};""", con=conn)['count'])[0]
        count_unmatched = total - count_matched
        percentage_matched = round(count_matched / total, 2)
        collator.loc[len(collator)] = [table, col, count_matched, count_unmatched, total, percentage_matched]

# Save to csv file
collator.to_csv('my_match_file.csv', index=False)
```